# Laravel and hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

I want to make registration page in Laravel (default scaffolded) with little tweak. I have two radio buttons above my inputs and I'm struggling with javascript here. Guest user have two options, (user or company), if user will choose "company" button it should show different inputs than "user" has. For now I have been looking hours in google, what is best way to do it, but everything I try is doesn't work. I suck at javascript..

I have tried something like that just for testing, but looks like I'm again heading wrong way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('user').checked) {
        document.getElementById('#name').display = 'block';
    } else if (document.getElementById('company').checked) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, the 2 radio's are like:

```
<input type="radio" name="user_type" value="1" class="user_type"> User
<input type="radio" name="user_type" value="2" class="user_type"> Company
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.user_type').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 1 )
        { 
            // User section code here
        }
        else
        { 
            // Company section code here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach with steps and code:

1) Wrap your user and company input fields within a group class:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" id="user_radio_option">
<input type="radio" name="option" id="company_radio_option">
<div class="group" id="user-group">
    <!-- user input fields here -->
  <h1>User Group</h1>
</div>
<div class="group" id="company-group">
    <!-- company input fields here -->
  <h1>Company Group</h1>
</div>
```

2) Use JQuery to show or hide the created groups like:

```
$("#user_radio_option").click(function(){
    $("#user-group").css("display", "block");
    $("#company-group").css("display", "none");
});
$("#company_radio_option").click(function(){
    $("#company-group").css("display", "block");
    $("#user-group").css("display", "none");
});
```

3) Hide initially with css:

```
.group{
  display:none;
}
```

4) Since you are using Laravel in your controller you can do something like:

```
if($request->has('some_user_field')){
    //do validation for user
}else{
    //do validation for company
}
```

Of course there is a more elegant way to do this but since this is a simple task and you are new to JQuery that's how I would have get it done a couple of years ago when I was new to JQuery and Javascript. This should also work if the user uses tab and arrows to select your radio.

See working example at: https://codepen.io/ocanodiego/pen/ZKKyRR

Comment: I was just thinking now that i can change inputs, how can i validate company and user different. I was looking out multiauth, but thats better way to approach this. Thanks!